# civicrm upgrade - missing html cke editor on civimail

Tags: civimail

I am making the dreaded upgrade to drupal 9 from drupal 7. Civicrm is 5.40.1

I have just "rettached" the civicrm tables that were on the old drupal 7 site to the new site (fresh install drupal 9).

The html box (THE CKE editor) for civimail seems to have disappeared. I just have a gray box.

I have checked https://XXXXX/civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/display?reset=1

and I can see that the WYSIWYG is set to CKE version 4. I have already enabled and disabled the extension.

ON the drupal 9 side under text formats I can see that the administrator role can use full html.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: Any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Yes actually. I din't think to there  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
VM126:252 Uncaught Error: [CKEDITOR.resourceManager.load] Resource name "default" was not found at "https://XXXXX/core/assets/vendor/ckeditor/styles.js?t=qzqljs".
    at window.CKEDITOR.window.CKEDITOR.dom.CKEDITOR.resourceManager.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:252:450)
    at n (<anonymous>:248:123)
    at Array.v (<anonymous>:248:266)
    at x (<anonymous>:248:350)
    at HTMLScriptElement.CKEDITOR.env.ie.d.$.onerror (<anonymous>:249:354)

Comment: Did files get copied to /web/libraries/civicrm as part of the fresh install? And/or maybe a conflict with drupal's ckeditor since that error is mentioning drupal's copy.

Comment: Hum - not sure - I will check. If they didn't I assume they shoudl have been.....? Thanks